# What is the purpose of the plastic/rubber part in the centre of some CV driveshafts

Tags: part-identification, drive-shaft

Can someone help me identify what the plastic/rubber part around the centre of this CV driveshaft is? Does it cover some sort of connection between two separate halves of the shaft, or does it have some other purpose?

[image]

Comment: What vehicle (year/make/model) is the shaft used on?

Comment: The one I have is from a Mitsubishi Outlander PHEV (UK Model). The above photo is just an example image.

Comment: Mine is from a 2016 Mitsubishi Outlander PHEV (rear driveshafts).

Comment: The reason I ask is because different applications could have it for different reasons.

Comment: Yeah, quite possibly. I can't imagine manufacturers would put a joint into the driveshaft, so maybe it's some sort of weight to counter vibration?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would bet because of the length, to put to two long pieces together. I've not had to deal with it on anything, nor have I seen it before now. All I can see is a weak shaft because of it. You might be right with the idea of counter vibration.

Comment: I believe that's a slip joint to allow the length of the shaft to change as the wheel moves up and down due to suspension travel.

Comment: @jwh20 feel free to add that as an answer, rather than a comment. I thought that CV joints were designed that the tripod ends could slide in and out of their cups to allow for a change in length, but maybe this is also needed.